# Not able to communicate between different pods using gRPC

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, grpc, grpc-java

I have just implemented gRPC for interservice communication in my application. It works fine on my local network and even using docker images but when I deployed my services with gRPC in them using Kubernetes I got the following error:

```
10-10-2023 05:22:07.282 WARN  [http-nio-8029-exec-4,,,,msb-epak-service]---c.m.e.s.c.a.Actions$ErrorHandlerAction: Error while executing action. Error Type: class io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException, Message: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
        at io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException.fillInStackTrace(StatusRuntimeException.java:68)
        at io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException.<init>(StatusRuntimeException.java:58)
        at io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException.<init>(StatusRuntimeException.java:50)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:268)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:249)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:167)
        at com.msb.grpc.UserServiceGrpc$UserServiceBlockingStub.getEsignatureImage(UserServiceGrpc.java:503)
        at com.msb.sign.interservice.client.UserSignGRPCClient.getEsignatureImage(UserSignGRPCClient.java:61)
        at com.msb.sign.handler.ESignHandler.validateAndGetUserSignature(ESignHandler.java:203)
        at com.msb.sign.handler.ESignHandler.handle(ESignHandler.java:116)
        at com.msb.sign.handler.ESignHandler.handle(ESignHandler.java:62)
        at com.
Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: user/10.109.30.247:41474
```

I have created a UserServer in my user application and user api clients in the services that need to use the User Service. I haven't specified the ports for gRPC application as I am using [gRPC Spring Boot Starter](https://yidongnan.github.io/grpc-spring-boot-starter/en/server/getting-started.html).
I rely on my discovery service for finding the services and this works fine on my local as well as on docker images.

I have tried to whitelist gRPC IP on k8s but this is good for long term as whenever is service rebooted new port is allocated for gRPC service in that specific service.
My yaml file for server service:

```
server:
  port: 8000

gateway:
  port: ${GATEWAY_PORT:8081}

management:
  health:
    ldap:
      enabled: false
grpc:
  server:
    port: 0
  security:
    auth:
      enabled: false
  client:
    msb-epak-service:
      address: 'discovery:///msb-epak-service'
      enable-keep-alive: true
      keep-alive-without-calls: true
      negotiation-type: plaintext
    msb-config-service:
      address: 'discovery:///msb-config-service'
      enable-keep-alive: true
      keep-alive-without-calls: true
      negotiation-type: plaintext
```

Comment: Did you follow the documentation on port 9090? https://yidongnan.github.io/grpc-spring-boot-starter/en/kubernetes.html

Comment: I read it but this is the case when I have a different gRPC service that serves all my services. Right now I have a gRPC server in my services itself and properties are defined in application.yml file:
grpc:
  server:
    port: 0
  security:
    auth:
      enabled: false

Comment: @Hackerman also this is the case when port is set for application to be run on. I am right now considering the possibility of scalability of my services and due to which I cannot bind it to one port.

Comment: Can you add the yaml files that you are using for deployment on k8s?

Comment: @Hackerman mentioning it in my post.